# This.username is undefined in ionViewDidLoad() but defined in ionViewWillLeave() - Ionic3 chat mobile application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create a simple chat application with Ionic 3 and Firebase. Registering, logging in users, sending and displaying their messages work. This is a common chat room for all users.

I'd like a message to appear in the chat room when a user is logged in or logged out to let other users know. When test user is logged in, this message appears: "has joined the room"

When test user is logged out, this message appears: "test@gmail.com has left the room"

I'd like the username (email address) to show when the user is logged in as well. I'd like this message to appear: "test@gmail.com has joined the room"

I tried write this.username on the console, but it only writes this to the console: ionViewDidLoad ChatPage. The username doesn't appear on the console:
console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage', this.username);

chat.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import $ from 'jquery';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {

  username: string= '';
  message: string= '';
  obsRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  obsToData: Subscription;
  messages: object[]= [];

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
      this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }
    });

    this.obsRef = this.db.object('/chat');
    this.obsToData = this.obsRef.valueChanges().subscribe( data => {
      var data_array= $.map(data, function(value, index) {            
        return [value];
      });

      this.messages= data_array;
    });
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      username: this.username,
      message: this.message
    }).then( () => {
      this.message= '';
    });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log('user is about to go');
    this.obsToData.unsubscribe();

    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      specialMessage: true,
      message: this.username + `has joined the room`
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage', this.username);

    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      specialMessage: true,
      message: this.username + `has joined the room`
    })
  }
}
```

chat.html:

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Chat</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

<div id="chatMessages">
  <div *ngFor="let message of messages" [class]="message.specialMessage ? 'message special': 'message'">
    <div [class]="message.username == username ? 'innerMessage messageRight': 'innerMessage messageLeft'">
      <div class="username"> {{ message.username }} </div>
      <div class="messageContent"> {{ message.message }} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <div id="footer">
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "message"> </ion-input>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)= "sendMessage()">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are getting the username from Storage. 
That is an Async operation, which means it can happen before or after ionViewLoad event. 
this means in the following lines

```
  this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
  if (val != null) { // this will run later
    this.username= val; 
  }
```

the constructor will exist without anything in the 'then' being executed. those lines will run later whenever the storage has the results ready.

think of it as putting an order for data. Just because you have put in the order, does not mean your order has arrived.

looks like by the time you leave the view, the call to storage has finished and username is set.

I suggest you wait somehow for the username to arrive like

```
<div id="chatMessages" *ngIf="username?.length > 0">
```

And even better that that, refactor your code so that you have username ready by the time you get to this view. after all this view is not usable without having a username ready.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to save the username in messages.message (object[]). I set this.username in the constructor. Shouldn't the constructor already be called by the time ionViewDidLoad() is called?

Comment: you are not setting the username in constructor, you are telling the storage to load a value and 'when' value is ready, set it to the username. this means constructor will exit without value being set yet. this is all about Asynchronous programming

Comment: Thank you, it works :) I passed the username to the chat page using NavController

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are using a tabbed layout. If that is the case, then try getting the stored result using `ionViewDidEnter()` so that everytime you enter the page the result gets updated. Try doing something like this and check,

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }
    });
}
```